# How can I delete a request.session variable inside the Django HTML template?

Tags: django, django-templates

Code:

```
{% if request.session.message %}
<div class="alert alert-warning alert-dismissible fade show" role="alert">
    <i class="bi bi-check2-circle"></i> {{request.session.message}}
    <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"></button>
</div>
{% endif %}
{% request.session.remove('message') %}
```

Error:

TemplateSyntaxError at /
Could not parse the remainder: '('message')' from 'request.session.remove('message')

Comment: Please use Django's message framework, this automatically will remove rendered messages: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/contrib/messages/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the sessions mechanism to post messages to a user, but Django already has tools for that in place: [*Django's messages framework*](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/contrib/messages/). In fact the default storage mechanism of these messages *are* the session variables.

The messages framework however makes it easy to let Django do bookkeeping about what messages the user has seen, and makes it easy to deliver *multiple* messages to the user. Furthermore one can give the messages a certain severity level.

You install the messages framework by specifying as [**`MIDDLEWARE`** setting [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#middleware) both `'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware'` and `'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware'`. Furthermore the `'django.contrib.messages'` app should be in in [**`INSTALLED_APPS`** setting [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#installed-apps). this is by default already the case, and for the [**`TEMPLATES`** setting [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#templates), you should add `'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages'` to the `'context_processors'` key, so the settings should look like:

```
# settings.py

# …

MIDDLEWARE = [
    # …,
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    # …,
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.MessageMiddleware'
    # …
]

# …

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    # …,
    'django.contrib.messages',
    # …
]

# …

TEMPLATES = [
    {
       # …,
       'context_processors': [
           # …,
           'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages'!!!,
           # …
       ]
       # …
    }
]

# …
```

You can then add a message to the `request` object with:

```
from django.contrib import messages

# …

messages.warning(request, 'Some warning')
```

Then in the template, you can render the messages with:

```
{% for message in messages %}
<div class="alert alert-warning alert-dismissible fade show" role="alert">
    <i class="bi bi-check2-circle"></i> {{ message }}
    <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"></button>
</div>
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score -1):

**For people who wants to clear the session storage from Django templates [Not just messages]**

#### index.html

```html
<form action="/" method="get">
    <input type="button" name="clear" hidden="True">
    <input type="submit" value="clear session">
</form>
```

#### views.py

```py
def index(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        if "clear" in dict(request.GET):
            request.session = {}
    return render(request, 'index.html')
```

Comment: OP asked for the solution, if the session can be deleted inside Template, this solution doesn't delete the session nor its being done on template